# c# code improvement (arrays, lists)

Tags: c#

I was wondering if somebody could help me improve my code (?)

Three weeks ago I decided that it would be very useful to learn C#/C++ (decided to start with c#) and I'm doing my best, but I have problems with understanding some basics- for example arrays.

I would like to add "x" textboxes (where "x" is the value form numericUpDown) with a button click.

I found a solution how to do this, but I have this feeling that it is possible to write this in a different (better) way ( I assume advanced programers would use lists or arrays).

Please forgive me if I'm wrong, as I mentioned before- I'm new and doing my best to learn.

Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (numericUpDown1.Value == 1)
    {
        txtbx1.AutoSize = true;
        Controls.Add(txtbx1);
        txtbx1.Location = new Point(70, 100);
    }
    else if (numericUpDown1.Value == 2)
    {
        txtbx1.AutoSize = true;
        Controls.Add(txtbx1);
        txtbx1.Location = new Point(70, 100);

        txtbx2.AutoSize = true;
        Controls.Add(txtbx2);
        txtbx2.Location = new Point(70, 130);
    }
    else if (numericUpDown1.Value == 3)
    {
        txtbx1.AutoSize = true;
        Controls.Add(txtbx1);
        txtbx1.Location = new Point(70, 100);

        txtbx2.AutoSize = true;
        Controls.Add(txtbx2);
        txtbx2.Location = new Point(70, 130);

        txtx3.AutoSize = true;
        Controls.Add(txtbx3);
        txtbx3.Location = new Point(70, 160);
    }
}
```

Comment: this question would be more appropriate on board `code review` http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: take a look at `switch` statements

Comment: From the StackOverflow "About" page: "Not all questions work well in our format. Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers.". A question in this format is very subjective. It doesn't have any problems per se, and if it was more complicated, there would be many more *opinions* on how to accomplish what you are trying to do. That's why @Chips_100 suggested going to a different site. I actually didn't know about codereview.stackeschange.com!! I'm excited to have learned about it just now. Just an FYI for the future.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't repeat yourself, in a simple way you can do like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    int y = 100;
    int x = 70;
    for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
    {
        var txtbx = new TextBox();
        txtbx.AutoSize = true;
        Controls.Add(txtbx);
        txtbx.Location = new Point(x, y);

        // Increase the y-position for next textbox.
        y += 30;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Instead of pre-creating the `TextBox` controls, you could always create them on the fly:

```
// This is optional - in case you want to save these for use later.
List<TextBox> newTextBoxes = new List<TextBox>();

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int y = 100;
     for (int i=0;i<numericUpDown1.Value;++i)
     {
         TextBox newBox = new TextBox
         {
            AutoSize = true,
            Location = new Point(70, y)
         };
         y += 30;
         Controls.Add(newBox);

         // This saves these for later, if required
         newTextBoxes.Add(newBox);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do one of two things. The first is to use a `switch` statement, or my preference is to use a loop, though this can get a little tricky when using a gui. Something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numericUpDown1.Value; i++)
    {
        //Make an TextBox Array or instantiate a new TextBox each iteration
            //and set properties here
    }
```

But as I said, the placement of these text boxes can get a little tricky if you do it in a loop, so it would be easier to just use the `switch` statement. They are relatively straightforward to use, but let us know if you run into any problems.

Also, a note on your code, give the text boxes and other GUI elements meaningful names; I know the designer automatically assigns them names and it's not a problem now, but it will become extremely confusing when working with many elements.